# Run swift code on main thread in react-native

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I am trying to make a react-native app cast to chromecast. The chromecast GCKDeviceScanner has to run on the main thread.

The react native page says to run on main thread you have to do this:

```js
- (dispatch_queue_t)methodQueue
{
  return dispatch_get_main_queue();
}
```

I am not very familiar with swift or ios, so where do I put this code, and how do I use it? I have my method:

```js
let filterCriteria = GCKFilterCriteria(forAvailableApplicationWithID: "myApp")
    
    let deviceScanner = GCKDeviceScanner(filterCriteria: filterCriteria)
    if let deviceScanner = deviceScanner {
      deviceScanner.addListener(self)
      deviceScanner.startScan()
      deviceScanner.passiveScan = true
    }
```

Any idea on how I can run my code on the main thread?

Comment: I'm not sure what react-native is but, the default thread is the main thread. Unless you're calling that code on a thread other than the main thread then you shouldn't need to do anything. In the case that you are, here is a website to assist you: https://www.raywenderlich.com/60749/grand-central-dispatch-in-depth-part-1

Comment: React native is a framework developed by Facebook for writing native apps using javascript. Where it lacks in the javascript it lets you build your own native modules. It says about threading this: 
"React Native invokes native modules methods on a separate serial GCD queue". So it does not let you in on the main thread unless you specify to use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To run that code section in the main thread, you can do this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  let filterCriteria = GCKFilterCriteria(forAvailableApplicationWithID: "myApp")
  
  let deviceScanner = GCKDeviceScanner(filterCriteria: filterCriteria)
  if let deviceScanner = deviceScanner {
    deviceScanner.addListener(self)
    deviceScanner.startScan()
    deviceScanner.passiveScan = true
  }
}
```

Another option is `RunLoop.main.perform { .. }`.

Old version, before Swift 4 (maybe even 3?):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
  let filterCriteria = GCKFilterCriteria(forAvailableApplicationWithID: "myApp")
  
  let deviceScanner = GCKDeviceScanner(filterCriteria: filterCriteria)
  if let deviceScanner = deviceScanner {
    deviceScanner.addListener(self)
    deviceScanner.startScan()
    deviceScanner.passiveScan = true
  }
}
```